# Slow Dlookup call in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access front end/back end database.  In the back end database I have a table keyed on FundCode.  The table has 4 fields and 150 records.  In the front end I have a form used to update a different table in the back end.  When the user enters the FundCode on this form, I want to display the data in the three columns on the form - so the use can check they have chosen the correct fund code.  To display this I am using a textbox (not enabled) to display with a control being a Dlookup into my fund table e.g.

```
=DLookUp("ISIN","tbl_FundMap","FundCode = " & [FundCode])
```

The code does what it supposed to do, but when I have around 100 entries in the form the it takes around 10 sec to refresh the screen every time a user rolls up or down.  Any suggestions how I can achieve a quicker result?

Comment: read stack overflow guidelines

Comment: Sorry - just to add a comment - the process now refreshes at a sensible rate - I have no idea why - but it is now less than a second for a screen refresh.  This is what I expected, but now what I was experiencing earlier.  Would still appreciate any views on if there is a better way.  Thanks

Comment: @AdrianSlater do not add more data as comment, edit your question with everything needed in it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using text boxes and the `DLOOKUP` function, I would reccomend using combo boxes.

The first combo box is where the user selects the actual `FundCode` value. The 2nd combo box, which is locked and/or disabled, also has its control source set to `FundCode`, but its row source includes the `ISIN` as the 2nd column. That way, the 2nd combo box always shows the `ISIN` based on the current `FundCode` selected.

[image: Design View]

[image: Form View]

Comment: Thanks Zak - not the solution I used, but set me on the right track.  I did experiment with a vba call to use caching (cannot understand why that similar question did not appear when I entered my question but did appear when I posted).  I amended my form query to directly to my reference table which I did not do at first because I was scared of getting the "must use an updateable query" message.  Thanks for the help.